# LWJGL: glTexImage2D implementation

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a texture from an array of integers using this code from these two classes. When I bind the texture i just get black.

```
public class PTexture {

private int id;
private int width;
private int height;

public PTexture(int id, int width, int height)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public Vector2f[] getRectPortionCoords(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    Vector2f[] res = new Vector2f[4];

    res[0] = new Vector2f((float)x / w, (float)y / height);
    res[1] = new Vector2f((float)(x + w) / width,(float)y / height);
    res[2] = new Vector2f((float)(x + w) / width, (float)(y + h) / height);
    res[3] = new Vector2f((float)x / w, (float)(y + h) / height);

    return res;
}

public void bind()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

```
public class TerrainBlend extends PTexture {

private int[] pixels;

public TerrainBlend(int id, int width, int height) {
    super(id, width, height);
    pixels = new int[width * height];
}

public void genPixelsFromHeight(float[][] hMap, Vector3f colorHeights)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x++)
        {
            if (hMap[x][y] >= colorHeights.getX())
            {
                genPixel(x, y, 0xFF0000FF);
                if (hMap[x][y] >= colorHeights.getY())
                {
                    genPixel(x, y, 0x00FF00FF);
                    if (hMap[x][y] >= colorHeights.getZ())
                    {
                        genPixel(x, y, 0x0000FFFF);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    genTexture();
}

private void genPixel(int x, int y, int color)
{
    pixels[x + y * getWidth()] = color;
}

public void genTexture()
{   
    IntBuffer iBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(getWidth() * getHeight() * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
    {
        iBuffer.put(pixels[i]);
    }
    iBuffer.position(0);

    setId(glGenTextures());
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, getId());
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, iBuffer);
}
```

}

I've made sure the values in the array are correct and they are so I'm assuming the OpenGL code is wrong in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a couple of problems:

- The type you pass to the `glTexImage2D()` will not work the way you probably intended:

  ```
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0,
               GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, iBuffer);
  ```

  Using `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` for a texture with a `GL_RGBA` internal format means that a `GLuint` value from the buffer will be used for each **component** of the texture. I.e. four values will be used for each texel, one each for R, G, B, and A.

  Based on how you build the values, it looks like you have the RGBA components for each texel packed in one value. To have the data interpreted that way, you need to specify a format that specifies packed values:

  ```
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0,
               GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, iBuffer);
  ```
- You need to specify texture parameters. Particularly, the default sampling attributes assume that the texture has mipmaps, which your texture does not. At the very least, you need a call to set the minification mask to no use mipmaps:

  ```
  glTexParameter(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  ```